# HSSF - How to keep Date data type when exporting to excel using HSSF

Tags: date, hssf

I am using POI-HSSF to export some data to excel. Requirement is I need to keep data type of each column. I can keep data type for string and numeric values but not the date. I studied in POI documentation that it supports only 3 basic data types string, numeric and boolean.

Can anyone please tell me how can I keep the 'Date' data type when exporting to excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up [DateUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html) offered by poi.

The way you check for String, numeric and boolean data types, you can use [`isCellDateFormatted`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) the same was and get the date cell value (`getDateCellValue`) - which you can keep, reformat or use them in your customized way.

Comment: Can you please share the detail of dll and its version you are refering

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could some example for .net C# as I am newbie for NPOI

Comment: @user3480558 it wasn't clear from the question which language and library you were referring to. I'd suggest you open a new question with proper C# and npoi tags to get the relevant response.